# Finding a substring of A string using only methods length, charAt and substring()

Tags: java, string, methods

I have a task in which two strings are stored in separate variables and I will have to check if string1 is a substring of string2? Only problem is that I can only use the  `length()`, `charAt()` and `substring()` methods.

Anyone know a way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this(you won't need `charAt()`):

```
    String string1 = "abc";
    String string2 = "aba";

    int l = string1.length();
    boolean flag = false;
    int i = 0;

    while (true) {
        if (l > string2.length() && !flag) {
            break;
        }
        if (string1.equals(string2.substring(i, l))) {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
        i++;
        l++;
    }

    if (flag)
        System.out.println("Contains");
    else
        System.out.println("Does not Contain");
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. I was doing something similar however using charAt() which will iterate through the second string using a for loop. Once the character is found which is the same as the second string, i will use a substring. string2.substring(position, str1.length()); but i was getting exception bound error. Thanks.

Comment: Yah, for that error you just need an extra check `if((position + string1.length()) > string2.length())`